# Find the base of Rhombus given a circle inside.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Given a Rhombus with a tangential circle inside with radius $R$, find the area of the Rhombus. When trying to approach this question, I found that the height is $2R$ because the circle touches the top and the bottom of the Rhombus perpendicularly. However, I fail to understand how the base of the Rhombus would be $2R$ from symmetry. The angle at B is 60 degrees.

[image]

Comment: The information in the problem as you have stated it is insufficient. A rhombus of arbitrarily large area may have a circle of radius $R$ inscribed in it. Can you include the original verbatim problem statement in the question? Also, who says the base of the rhombus would be $2R$?

Comment: You should use property of right triangle with angle 60°. That means that rombus height is equal $\sqrt{a^2-(a/2)^2}$.

Comment: $\triangle ACD, ADB$ are equilateral triangles with height $2r$. From there you can find the side, then the area.

Answer (score 2):

I am indebted to @Blue who has pointed a misunderstanding of the question. This is the corrected version.

Let us first consider the general case : for a given circle with radius $R$, there exists rhombi having it as an inscribed circle with side lengths $L$ varying from $2R$ (the case of a square: black lines) to $\infty$:

[image]

Let us call $B$ the upper vertex of the rhombus, and still consider the general case but with the unit circle $(R=1)$ ; the equation of the tangent line touching this circle in point $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ is $$x \cos \theta + y \sin \theta = 1$$

We can assume without loss of generality that

$$\theta>\pi/4 \tag{1}$$

Indeed, taking into account the different symmetries present in the figure (with respect to horizontal, vertical and diagonal axes), we can restrict our attention to tangent lines with slopes $\ge 1$ "crossing" the first quadrant $x>0, \ y>0$.

As a consequence of (1), such tangent lines intersect coordinate axes in $A(1/\cos \theta,0)$ and $B(0,1/\sin \theta)$ giving (Pythagoras):

$$L^2:=length(AB)^2 =\frac{1}{\cos^2 \theta}+\frac{1}{\sin^2 \theta}$$

$$L^2 =\frac{4}{(2\sin \theta \cos \theta)^2}=\frac{4}{\sin^2 (2 \theta)}$$

$$L =\frac{2}{|\sin (2 \theta)|} \tag{1}$$

Now, at last, we can consider the particular case where the angle in $B$ is $\pi/3$ ($ = 60°$). Therefore, angle OBA = $pi/6$. A little angle chasing gives $\theta=\pi/6$ as well.

Plugging this value of $\theta$ in (1) gives

$$L=\frac{2}{\sin (\pi/3)} = \frac{4}{\sqrt{3}}$$

for a unit radius. For a general radius $R$, the final answer is

$$L= \frac{4}{\sqrt{3}} R$$

**Final remark:** I recognize that my presentation can surely be ranked as "overkill" (the particularity of the 60° angle can be used for a splitting of the rhombus into 2 equilateral triangles, yielding a direct solution, as remarked in comments). The only advantage of the above approach is its generality: any similar problem on rhombi can be undertaken with this parameter $\theta$.

Comment: +1. However, OP has added the detail that $\angle B = 60^\circ$.

Comment: @Blue Indeed ! Once more, I hadn't be sufficiently attentive ! I will make an Edit.

Comment: @Blue Fixed. A big thank.